# Best Blowfish command line tool?

Tags: command-line, encryption, blowfish

Our application needs to encrypt/decrypt files using (for instance) Blowfish encryption algorithm.  We know [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) could be a good choice, but it cannot be called directly from our application (as it prompts for key phrase).

Which is the best existing option?

We prefer a Windows tool, though Linux would be good as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/blowfish.html  programming interface

http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html   command line interface

Example:

```
openssl enc -base64 -e -bf-cbc -in <infile> -out <outfile> -kfile <passphrase file>
```

(replace `-e` with `-d` to decrypt)

Comment: Omit `-kfile <passphrase file>` to have openssl prompt for password.

Answer (score 2):

I coudln't find one I liked; so I wrote one in Go. Here it is: https://prologic.github.io/fish/

**Example:**

$ echo 'Hello World' | fish -e -k mysecret -

Pretty easy to install with:

$ go get github.com/prologic/fish

Also supports both Blowfish and the newer Twofish